# youtube api for xamarin

Tags: c#, youtube-api, xamarin

I'm looking for any library or simple project for youtube api and include it into my project. Main problem is that I'm working in xamarin and there's some problems for include input jar. Somebody has had a similar problem?

Answer (score 5):

Xamarin has Google API bindings on their Github

https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis

Answer (score 0):

A native Youtube API with Xamarin bindings Xamarin can be found at Github:

https://github.com/nishanil/YouTubeAndroidPlayer